# Why can't we declare namespace aliases inside a class?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-design

It looks like it's impossible to declare a namespace alias inside a class; however we can do so at function-level (tested with g++ 4.3.4) :

```
namespace A
{
}

class C
{
  namespace N = A; // error: expected unqualified-id before `namespace'
};

class D
{
  void f();
};

void D::f()
{
  namespace N = A; // OK
}
```

Any idea why such a restriction exists ? This doesn't seem very consistent with typedefs which can be declared inside a class.

Comment: +1, I did not know that this was possible: `namespace N = A;`

Comment: @Alexandre I guess he wants something like this namespace `A = A1::A2::A3::A4;`

Comment: btw +1 as this is new for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert on the C++ Standard but I'll stick my neck out and have a go at answering your question. I assume the use of `namespace N = A` within a class declaration falls foul of the definition of how a class member should be defined.

The C++ Standard defines a class member as

```
member-specification:
  member-declaration member-specification_opt
  access-specifier : member-specification_opt
member-declaration:
  decl-specifier-seq_opt member-declarator-list_opt ;
  function-definition ;opt
  ::opt nested-name-specifier templateopt unqualified-id ;
  using-declaration
  static_assert-declaration
  template-declaration
member-declarator-list:
  member-declarator
  member-declarator-list , member-declarator
member-declarator:
  declarator pure-specifier_opt
  declarator constant-initializer_opt
  identifier_opt : constant-expression
pure-specifier:
  = 0
constant-initializer:
  = constant-expression
```

The important point being the `=` in the declaration, the compiler is expecting either a pure-specifier or constant-initializer statement and as the line does not end in a zero, we are not applying a pure-specifier in this case.

Analysing the `namespace N = A` declaration the compiler sees this as

```
declarator = constant-expression
```

And since `namespace` is a keyword it cannot be used.

`typedef` is permitted because (from the standard)

> Nested types are classes and enumerations defined in the class, 
>   and arbitrary types declared as members by use of a typedef declaration.

Comment: This is informative but not educative. Why did the comitee made this decision ? that's what I want to know. My bet is because they forsaw a can of worms caused by ADL.

Answer (score 6):

According C++ standard 3.3.6

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1) The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the name’s declarator, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, and constructor ctor- initializers in that class (including such things in nested classes).
>   ...........

So you can declare only things from this list in class scope. Declaring anything else in class scope isn't valid. Not only namespace alliance, but also namespace. For example

```
class myClass
{
    //compilation error !!!
    namespace myNamespace
    {
    }
    using namespace std;//another compilation error
}
```

**Edit:**

> Any idea why such a restriction exists ? This doesn't seem very consistent with typedefs which can be declared inside a class.

Because using typedefs in classes are very usefull (for example `vector<int>::iterator`), while for namespaces it's useless. Consider following code

```
class myClass
{
   namespce N=std;
};

//now let's use N
MyClass::N::vector<int> v;//don't you think, that this syntax is horrible, and useless?????
```

For comparison see what it is doing in function

```
void f()
{
    namespace bnu= boost::numeric::ublas;
    bnu::matrix<int> m;//and now we can use short name bnu
}
```

For class we can declare namespace alliance in cpp file and  there is  **NO NEED** to daclare it in class declaration.

Comment: Ok not a personal attack but you are wrong man :) use your own example of `bnu` and note that now you can use `bnu` in `myClass` methods's arguments which is very useful, as well as return values (in declarations). Also your wording at the top `only things from this list` makes no sense, you refer to declarative regions, they are not usable. MOREOVER, you can declare typedefs and inner classes at class scope. as well as `using base::method` and static_assert. Forbidding namespaces must have another motivation that's outside of anything mentioned on this page.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that namespace declaration within a class is completely useless.  It would be useful to be able to declare enumerations within namespaces within classes.  This would alow you to access the elements of different arrays with logical indices for the specific array.

```
class myClass
{
   private:
        namespace TransAndRotIdx {
            enum { U, V, W, P, Q, R }; };
        namespace RotIdx {
            enum { P, Q, R }; };
        double tr[6];
        double r[3];

    public:
        double getTranslationMag(void)
        {
            using namespace TransAndRotIdx;
            return sqrt(tr[U]*tr[U]+tr[V]*tr[V]+tr[W]*tr[W]);
        }
        double getRotationMag(void)
        {
            using namespace RotIdx;
            return sqrt(tr[P]*tr[P]+tr[Q]*tr[Q]+tr[R]*tr[R]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record, in C++11 you can basically accomplish this with `enum class` (but without the benefit of the `using` declaration).